# Timer Updating Label 1 Second Behind 2nd Timer Counting Down

Tags: ios, swift, nstimer, countdown

I'm having difficulties attempting to link two timers together. I'm trying to have a timer count down from a specified amount and to have a second timer constantly updating a label on a view controller. However, I end up having the timer that updates the label lagging exactly 1 second behind the first timer in the timer class. Here's what I have for the view controller: (note that this is a condensed version of my code)

```
class HomeViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var timeLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        timeLabel.text = account.deedManager.globalTimer.timerStr

        Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.05, target: self, selector: #selector(UpdateTime), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    @objc func UpdateTime() {
            self.timeLabel.text = account.deedManager.globalTimer.timerStr
    }
}
```

And here is the Timer class:

```
class TimerModel: NSObject, NSCoding {
    var myTimer: Timer? = Timer()
    var timerInterval: TimeInterval = 1.0
    var timerEnd: TimeInterval = 0.0
    var timerCount: TimeInterval = 86400.0 // 24 hours
    var timerStr: String = "TIME"

    func StartTimer(time: Double) {
        timerCount = time
        myTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(UpdateTime), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    @objc func UpdateTime() {
        self.timerStr = self.TimerDate(time: self.timerCount)
        self.timerCount-=1
        print(self.timerStr)
    }

    func TimerDate(time:TimeInterval) -> String {
        let hours = Int(time) / 3600
        let minutes = Int(time) / 60 % 60
        let seconds = Int(time) % 60
        return String(format: "%02i:%02i:%02i", hours, minutes, seconds)
    }
}
```

I've tried to make the first timer a 0.05 interval so that it updates more rapidly than the timer class, but it lags behind exactly a second no matter what interval I put it at. I don't want to put the count down timer inside the view controller as I want the timer global for all view controllers. If you have any ideas, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You have this function:

```
@objc func UpdateTime() {
    self.timerStr = self.TimerDate(time: self.timerCount)
    self.timerCount-=1
    print(self.timerStr)
}
```

Replace it with

```
@objc func UpdateTime() {
    self.timerCount-=1
    self.timerStr = self.TimerDate(time: self.timerCount)
    print(self.timerStr)
}
```

Explanation:
You first have to *change* the value, then *display* it

Notice the first two lines are swapped. This should fix your issue.

Comment: Hmm, now it's lagging by 2 seconds instead of one. So that's not the issue.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to switch the order around so that you are setting the text after you decrement the `timerCount`:

```
@objc func UpdateTime() {
    self.timerCount-=1
    self.timerStr = self.TimerDate(time: self.timerCount)
    print(self.timerStr)
}
```

Then, you can delete the 0.05-second timer because as you said, that doesn't seem to work.

Try using the delegate pattern instead.

```
protocol TimerModelDelegate {
    func timerTextDidChange(_ timer: TimerModel, text: String)
}
```

And then in `TimerModel`,

```
weak var delegate: TimerModelDelegate?
var timerStr: String = "TIME" {
    didSet {
        delegate?.timerTextDidChange(self, text: timerStr)
    }
}
```

In `HomeViewController`, do this:

```
class HomeViewController: UIViewController, TimerModelDelegate {
    @IBOutlet var timeLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        timeLabel.text = account.deedManager.globalTimer.timerStr
        account.deedManager.globalTimer.delegate = self
        account.deedManager.globalTimer.StartTimer(time: 60)
    }

    // You don't need the UpdateTime method here

    func timerTextDidChange(_ timer: TimerModel, text: String) {
        timeLabel.text = text
    }
}
```

Comment: The code works, but the 1 sec delay is still there.

Comment: @Klaviam Can you tell me how you find out that there is a 1 second delay? Is there a difference between the time printed and the time on the label?

Comment: Yes; the print() line feeds output to the console of the true time. However, the label on the viewcontroller is 1 second behind.

Comment: @Klaviam I cannot reproduce this behaviour. Are you sure this is not caused by some other parts of your code that slows the UI down or something? I have also edited the answer to correct some typos. Does it work now?